# Google Script EPOCH date creation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Script that needs to get 2 specific dates.

1) The second day of the previous month at 8 am GMT
2) The first day of the current month at 8 am GMT

Both dates need to be converted to EPOCH times.

I built this on a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qdmf8gd7/2/):

```
  var a = new Date();
  var year = a.getFullYear();
  var month = a.getMonth();
  if(month === 0){
    var startDate = new Date((year-1)+'-12-02 08:00 GMT');
    var endDate = new Date(year+'-'+(month+1)+'-01 08:00 GMT');
  }else{
    var startDate = new Date(year+'-'+month+'-02 08:00 GMT');
    var endDate = new Date(year+'-'+(month+1)+'-01 08:00 GMT');
  }
```

This works perfectly fine, however when I use that in Google Script, the `new Date()` fails and returns NaN. I've read that it has to do with the JS version that Google Script uses, but couldn't find anything on how to format that string above to go through cleanly.

What is the correct format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Replace the `-` in your date string with `/`.
2) For epoc do Date.getTime() /1000